# PyGame fullscreen with interesting issue under Win7

Tags: pygame

I stumbled across an interesting behaviour of Pygame under Win 7. The program I wrote has originally been tested under Win XP. When changing to the FULLSCREEN mode, it would "stretch" the images to fit the ratio of the fullscreen. Yet under Win7 it doesn't...
When I change to fullscreen, everything remains at its original size, instead of stretching the images, the borders are filled with my background colour.

Is this intentional or a bug? What behaviour would you expect in this case? I find it quit interesting, yet I'd like to have a way to stretch the images to fit the screen also under Win7, preferably without having to rescale them all (it's quite a number...).

Answer (score 1):

Pygame won't distort the aspect ratio of the image on the screen when switching to fullscreen, so when you set the display mode using

```
pygame.display.set_mode((width,height),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

black space will be added to fill in areas that are left open when the aspect ratio of your monitor doesn't match the ratio of width to height.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort but it seems that this is not the answer. I tried a resolution of 1920x1080 (my current screen resolution), which - of course - worked properly in fullscreen, and then 960x540 (which is also 1.77 : 1). It completely distorted the picture (stretching it in width).

Comment: Are you certain the height wasn't stretched to give the same aspect ratio? Is your monitor in wide mode (this was my issue once when the aspect ratio wasn't the same on a different computer)? Does your graphics adapter support a resolution of 960x540?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will have a closer look into this but it's going to take a while :) I will let you know once I experimented more.